# PDFTK doesn't stop executing (mac)

Tags: macos, pdftk

[image]

I run this command but it doesn't stop executing, though it's creating the output but it just stops there. When I run it to php exec() it just keeps loading cause the command doesn't terminate. Any ideas

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: This should be related for I am running this over exec() in php.

Comment: OK - the question could perhaps be a little clearer then - are you saying it runs OK from the command line but not when you exec it from PHP ? You should probably include the relevant PHP code just for completeness.

Comment: it runs both command line and php exec, the problem is when I ran it the execution is not terminating making it appear in the browser that it keeps on loading